# Connection issue during runtime database attach.

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have some problems in Linq-to-SQL connection, I have developed a desktop application using Linq-to-SQL in that I have used service based local database and I created one setup for this application in put that `.mdf` file in my setup project, now my problem is that when I create setup and installed it in other pc then it will show me error like

> BA network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)lockquote

My connection string is

```
 connectionString="AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DailyExpense.mdf; 
                   Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
```

Comment: Is that PC also have SqlExpress installed or not?

Comment: yes if SqlExpress is installed then it's give me same error.

Comment: is it required to installed client side SqlExpress while i am using .mdf file ?

Comment: Yes, .mdf file will not work until a Sql Server is not accessing that, because your application query to server, and if server is available then it can process that.

Comment: you mean to say client side SQLServer must installed?

Comment: Yes. The way you have created your application, sql server is required on the client. Yiu should not have included an mdf if you wanted to use a server.

Answer (score 1):

The way you have written the connection string suggests that you have SQL Server installed on the target machine. The format you have used "instructs" your application to try and attach the .mdf file you have supplied to the local RUNNING instance of the sql server. Should you want to use a remote server you would have to slightly rewrite the connection string to point to the server itself. Your connection string should look something similar to that:

```
data source=(MY MACHINE)\sqlexpress;initial catalog=DailyExpense;integrated security=True
```

Where:
- MY MACHINE will be the server on which the sql express instance is running.
- sqlexpress is the name of the sql instance (default is sqlexpress).
- DailyExpense is the name of the database (supposing that the database name is the same as the mdf file you have provided).

Comment: Thanks for your reply but i have doubt in your reply if i am writing data source =(MY Machine) that how would it works on target machine ?